# How can I access R (my package's R) to use Drwable image in Service

Tags: android, drawable

```
public class HelloService extends Service {


...
..
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(HelloService.this,MapActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);
//        Notification.InboxStyle style = new Notification.InboxStyle(mBuilder);
//
//
//        mBuilder.setStyle(style);
        mBuilder.setTicker("Notification.Builder");
        mBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        mBuilder.setNumber(10);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(android.support.v4.R.drawable.notification_icon_background);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        mBuilder.setContentText(contents);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        ***mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable ....);***
```

***//here I want to use icon to display . but for some reason,
 I can't use R.drawable(com.org.smartapp which mean my package). only there are android.support.v4 etc....How can I access to the drawable file to use it as icon? on other Java class file that extend activity can have R.drawable access like below . ***

[please click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6u9Q.png)

[can't find my packages one in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB6ld.png)

```
        mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN);

        nm.notify(111, mBuilder.build());

...
}
```

Comment: fox example, your package is: myapp.mobile.com then import this to your service: `import com.mobile.myapp.R;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 Drawable drawable=ContextCompat.getDrawable(HelloService.this,R.drawable.ic_launcher_round);
```